# ConcurrentModificationException even when no element is removed or added

Tags: java, exception, concurrentmodification

This piece of code block is throwing `ConcurrentModificationException` even though no element is added or removed, I even synchronized the block and there is only one instance of the containing class. Can anybody suggest anything, please?

```
    synchronized (HttpPlatform.lock) {
        while(servicesIterator.hasNext()) {
            Service service = servicesIterator.next(); // getting error from this line
            for(FixedBonusConfig config : configsForEName) {
                if((service.getCategory() != null && service.getCategory().equals(config.getCategory()) || config.getCategory().equals("Any")) && 
                        (service.getServiceline() != null && service.getServiceline().equals(config.getServiceline()) || config.getServiceline().equals("Any")) &&
                        (service.getTariffplan() != null && service.getTariffplan().equals(config.getTariff()) || config.getTariff().equals("Any")) &&
                        !isFraud(service, config)) {
                    if(config.getFixed_bonus() > highestBonus) {
                        highestBonus = config.getFixed_bonus();
                        highestYeildingConfig = config;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace for the exception

Comment: servicesIterator is created somewhere else, and presumably it or the underlying collection is being modified elsewhere.